# Is there any way to customize the order of multiple fields for forms.Form class with a field initiated by __init__?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When I render the form to a HTML template,
a certain field of form which is initiated by **init** is ordered always at bottom of table, even though I defined the field at the middle of form class.

Is there any way or method to customize the order of fields in the form where a initiated field exists by **init**.
I wanna put the field in the middle of form table in HTML template.

A screenshot of the rendered template:
[image]
In the screenshot, 
the field "category_name" is ordered at the bottom of  tag
I wanna change the order to the middle of table.

I am using Django 2.2 and python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Thanks

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category_name

class MakePurchaseLog(forms.Form):
    buy_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    shop = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakePurchaseLog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category_name'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices = [(item.category_name, item.category_name) \
                           for item in Category_name.objects. \
                           filter(owner=user)])
    goods_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    memo = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    field_order = ['category_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `__init__` is placed in the middle of the class, will not make any difference, since this is a function, and the evaluation is thus "postponed" until you actually create a `MakePurchaseLog` form object.

I think the most elegant solution here is to just already define the field in your form, and then in the `__init__` function alter the choices, like:

```
class MakePurchaseLog(forms.Form):

    buy_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    shop = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_name = forms.ChoiceField()
    goods_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    memo = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakePurchaseLog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category_name'].choices = [
            (item.category_name, item.category_name)
            for item in Category_name.objects.filter(owner=user)
        ]
```

We thus populate the `choices` of the `category_name` field in the `__init__` function, but we define the field already at the class level.

Comment: Thank you for your answering my question and helping me solve the problem. As you mention, I could fix it to reorder the field  at the middle!! Thank!